# Replace empty brackets in a json file using r

Tags: r

I have a large json file that I want to convert to a data frame with R thas some empty lines which look like this:

`{}`

After conversion these lines are gone thats why I want to put something in.

Can somebody help?

I tried using gsub like this (see below).

Unfortunately this doesn't work and all other lines that have some content are messed up afterwards.

Before `{}`

Code:

```
d <- gsub('[{}]', '{\"gender\": \"NA\", \"nationality\": \"NA\", \"document_type\": \"passport\", \"date_of_expiry\": \"2019-08-12\", \"issuing_country\": \"NA\"}' , d)
```

so after conversion I want all empty line `{}` to look like this:

```
{\"gender\": \"NA\", \"nationality\": \"NA\", \"document_type\": \"passport\", \"date_of_expiry\": \"2019-08-12\", \"issuing_country\": \"NA\"}
```

all other lines that have content e.g.

```
{\"gender\": \"Male\", \"nationality\": \"IRL\", \"document_type\": \"passport\", \"date_of_expiry\": \"2019-08-12\", \"issuing_country\": \"IRL\"}
```

I want to stay the same.

Comment: What is `d` in the code.  Here, you showed the replacement as the whole string.  Not clear

Answer (score 3):

This might be because brackets are used as special characters in regex rules (see [this cheatsheet](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/RegExCheatsheet.pdf)). Try escaping them, so something like `pattern = '\\{\\}'`.

If that doesn't work you could try using a different operator to simply identify where the occurrences are happening before removing them -- this might help you see what is going wrong and debug the issue.

Comment: how would I search for these? this "\\{\\}" did not work

Comment: Instead of escaping them, use `gsub("[{}]", '[{"gender":...}]', d, fixed=TRUE)`.

Comment: solved it with the search option you mentioned: #get empty lines
empty <- grep("\\{\\}", properties)

#fill empty lines
d[empty] <- "{\"gender\": \"NA\", \"nationality\": \"NA\", \"document_type\": \"passport\", \"date_of_expiry\": \"2019-08-12\", \"issuing_country\": \"NA\"}"